# excel formula to extract dates with highest trade count

Tags: excel

I need excel formula to show the dates when the trade count was maximum. Below mentioned are the excel columns

```
trade count.    date
10              9 jan
12              8 jan
12              7 jan
```

Result : 7 jan & 8 jan

so the result can be highlighted in two different rows. or whatever convenient format.
kindly advice how it can be done easily.

Answer (score 0):

Let your column C provide you with all the dates on which the MAX happens. You can always hide column C later.

Let C1 be the maximum from column A:

- `=MAX(A:A)`

Now in each row, column C can build up your final output string. Copy from C2 down:

- `=IF($C$1=A2,TEXT(B2, "dd mmm"),"")`

This gives you a column of either blank values, or the dates you need (correctly formatted as text).

---

Use column D to build up your final output string, by looking down column C:

- `=IF(C2="",IF(D3="","",D3),IF(D3="", C2,D3&" & "&C2))`

---

**Your result string will be given by cell D2.**

[image]